# How do I generate JSON schema RECURSIVELY with Newtonsoft.JSON?

Tags: .net, jsonschema, auto-generate

I've got a quite complicated object with lots of deeply nested objects. I'd like to generate a schema that covers not only 0-deep properties, but recursively covers the entire object.

So rather than

```
"complicatedObject": {
  "type": "object"
}
```

I'd like to see:

```
"complicatedObject": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": { 
      "yetAnotherComplicatedObject": ...,
      "primitiveProperty": ...,
      ...
   }
}
```

all the way down to the leaves.

Is there a way to achive that by Newtonsoft.JSON or any other .NET package?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is how to use `$ref` references.

Comment: http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#recursion

Comment: @Relequestual the question is how to force the framework to do that for me.

Comment: How to GENERATE... I see. Good luck with that. Seems rather unlikely that anything would support that because how would it know?